# Does metric vector space imply topological vector space?

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I do know that every normed vector space is also a topological vector space.

Is every metric (vector) space also a topological vector space.
I.e. is there a metric d, such that the induced topology is not continuous with the vector space operations?

Comment: I would define "metric vector space" as a metric space and a vector space where the vector operations are continuous according to the metric.  If that is your definition, then you should be able to answer your question.

Comment: If there’s no condition on $d$ whatsoever, then there’s no reason for vector space operations to be continuous with respect to $d$. For example, let $x_n \in \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence strictly decreasing to $0$. Let $f$ be a bijection of $\mathbb{R}$ that sends all $x_n$ to themselves and $0$ to anything other $0$, then the pullback of the Euclidean metric through $f$ defines a metric on $\mathbb{R}$, under which scalar multiplication is obviously not continuous.

Comment: In similar spirits, you can also construct an example in which the addition is not continuous.